# зачем в скобках перед строкой стоит символ "b"

Tags: python

В данном примере стоит символ "b" и без него функция не работает. Иногда в других функциях стоят и другие символы. Что они означают и как они называются?

```
import zlib
hex(zlib.crc32(b'hello-world') & 0xffffffff)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)

Comment: а как можно использовать этот литерал если вместо строки в кавычках  идет строка в переменной?

Comment: Какая строка, в какой переменной?..

Comment: к примеру вот так:
    var = 'bla bla bla';
    zlib.crc32(var);

Comment: `var = b'bla bla bla'`?

Comment: @bipll, будет круто, если вы приведёте хотя бы машинный перевод цитируемого текста)

Comment: Литералы типа `bytes` имеют префикс `b` перед открывающей кавычкой. Они состоят исключительно из символов из набора ASCII-7; символы с кодами 128 и более должны быть представлены эскейпами.

Answer (score 2):

Это [маркер литерала](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/), обозначающий, что за ним следует [последовательность байт](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).